# What is the correct place to add or remove ViewTreeObserver listeners?

Tags: android, android-activity

I can add the Listener to OnCreate or add it to OnResume and remove it OnPause. Is there a benefit of using one or the other implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we're talking of activity then you need to register the listener in the ViewTree in onCreate() method as the view is not measured yet and remove it in onDestroy().

In fragments, it should be registered in onViewCreated() and removed in onDestroyView()

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to android dev, what do you mean by view is not measured yet?

Comment: @verses It means that view hiearchy is not measured via the method onMeasrue. After attaching to a window object the top view group and its children are getting measured to calculate the sizes of each one. You need to read about the lifecycle of View in Android https://codentrick.com/android-view-lifecycle/

Comment: If you use `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` you're supposed to remove it ASAP, not in OnDestroy (or you keep getting the callback in an endless circle)

Comment: @MartinMarconcini it depends on your task. if you want to listen to view's layout changes always you can remove the listener when it's destroyed